How can I schedule a state change?
I want an org-heading to become a todo-heading in ten days. To my understanding, it should be possible with org-edna, but I can't figure out a way to do that. Any other methods I can use?

If your Emacs is running continuously, use a timer. If not, use cron. But I don't understand why you want to change the state: why not make it a TODO now and schedule it in ten days? The agenda will remind you at that point.

I don't want to schedule it as something that needs to be done at a specific date. It's a todo that is blocked by something like a date; it cannot be done before a date, but it also doesn't need to be done at that exact date. It's just not a TODO before that date. When that date arrives, it becomes a todo, which then gets dealt with based on priority of other tasks at that time.

"It's just not a TODO before that date." - OK, we know it's not a TODO. I guess the question is: what is it before that date?

Just an org-heading, or it could be another state, like BLOCKED.
